# reducebykey is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val ticker_data_rdd = ticker_data_parsed.
                      filter("date_stamp='2017-01-03 00:00:00.0' or date_stamp='2017-08-25 00:00:00.0'").
                      orderBy($"ticker",$"date_stamp".desc)

val ticker_data_pair_rdd = ticker_data_rdd.
                           map(x=> (x(0).toString,(x(2).toString.toDouble,x(3).toString.toDouble))).
                           reduceByKey((x,y)=> (y._1,x._2))
```

Please help in what is wrong in `ticker_data_pair_rdd`?

Answer (score 0):

Even though you call `ticker_data_rdd` it seems it's not an RDD but a Dataset so you can't use that method there

You can turn it into an RDD if you want to (I don't think that is be a good idea)

```
val ticker_data_pair_rdd = ticker_data_rdd
                           .map(x=> (x(0).toString,(x(2).toString.toDouble,x(3).toString.toDouble)))
                           .rdd
                           .reduceByKey((x,y)=> (y._1,x._2))
```

Or you can do the `reduceByKey` "equivalent" in dataset, something like this:

```
val ticker_data_pair_rdd = ticker_data_rdd
                           .map(x=> (x(0).toString,(x(2).toString.toDouble,x(3).toString.toDouble)))
                           .groupBy($"_1").agg(collect_list($"_2"))
```

Some info about RDD vs Dataset [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/07/14/a-tale-of-three-apache-spark-apis-rdds-dataframes-and-datasets.html)